# bug of mouse event in the function mouseReleaseEvent() of PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, mouseevent

code first:

```
class MyWidget(QMainWindow)
def __init__(self):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
    self.setMinimumSize(900, 500)
    self.setMouseTracking(True)

def mousePressEvent(self, e):
    if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
        print('left pressed')
    elif e.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
        print('right pressed')
    else:
        print('other button pressed')

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
    if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
        print('left up')
    elif e.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
        print('right up')
    else:
        print('other up')
```

just press the LEFT button, it outputs '**left pressed**', but when release the LEFT button, it outputs '**other up**', instead of '**left up**'!!

it happens to the RIGHT button in the same way.

Comment: Read the difference between [`button()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#button) and [`buttons()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#buttons).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `e.button()` instead of `e.buttons()`